# Ao exibir o site no celular, o input com o submit desconfigura. Como resolver ? Estou utilizando bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

**Site Exibido no computador:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Site exibido no celular:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue cod:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
 <title>Marcos Briseno - Livros</title>
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
  
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
   <div class="container">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Curso</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSite">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSite">


    <ul class=" navbar-nav mr-auto">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Perfil</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Serviços </a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Depoimentos</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contatos</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
     <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navDrop">
       Social
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Facebook</a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Twitter</a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Instagram</a>
      </div>

     </li>

    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline">
     <input class="form-control ml-4 mr-2 " type="search" placeholder="Buscar...">
     <button class="btn-inline btn-dark" type="submit">OK</button>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
   
        
     </nav>
 

 <section>
     <article>
         <header>
             <h2>O título do artigo é aqui</h2>
             <p>Publicado em <time datetime="2015-03-09T13:00:24+01:00">09 de Março de 2015</time> por <a href="#">Author</a> - <a href="#comments">30 comentários</a></p>
         </header>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
     </article>

     <article>
         <header>
             <h2>O título do artigo é aqui</h2>
             <p>Publicado em <time datetime="2015-03-09T13:00:24+01:00">09 de Março de 2015</time> por <a href="#">Author</a> - <a href="#comments">15 comentários</a></p>
         </header>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
     </article>
 </section>

 <aside>
     <h2>Entre em contato</h2>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
 </aside>

 <footer>
     <p>Copyright 2015 Código Fonte©</p>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cara coloca seu código na pergunta, só as imagens não ajudam a te responder

Comment: Feito. Ta lá o cod.

Comment: Inseri da forma correta agora.

Comment: Mas qual é o problema?

Comment: Queria colocar o OK na frente do BUSCAR. Ou senão alinhar ele abaixo do buscar. Veja como ficou desconfigurado.

Comment: Ao lado creio que não seja possível, se ver no próprio site do Bootstrap em barras de navegação, se diminuir a tela vai ver que o botão vai pra baixo do input, agora, para alinhar ele embaixo do input, basta retirar as margens que colocou mr-2 no input.

Comment: Fico massa LeAndrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu menu só é expandido em `lg` (`navbar-expand-lg`), correto? Então você pode só colocar a margem `ml-4` no input quando o viewport for `lg`. Em vez de `ml-4`, use `ml-lg-4`:

```
<input class="form-control ml-lg-4 mr-2 " type="search" placeholder="Buscar...">
```

Isso foi uma coisa, agora vamos ao principal:

Para evitar que o botão vá pra uma nova linha, basta colocar a classe nativa do Bootstrap `.flex-nowrap` no `form`:

```
<form class="form-inline flex-nowrap">
```

Problema resolvido e com bônus do lance da margem. ;)

Veja:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
      <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Curso</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSite">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSite">


         <ul class=" navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Perfil</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Serviços </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Depoimentos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contatos</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
               <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navDrop">
                  Social
               </a>
               <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Facebook</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Twitter</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Instagram</a>
               </div>

            </li>

         </ul>
         <form class="form-inline flex-nowrap">
            <input class="form-control ml-lg-4 mr-2 " type="search" placeholder="Buscar...">
            <button class="btn-inline btn-dark" type="submit">OK</button>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
      
       
    </nav>


<section>
    <article>
        <header>
            <h2>O título do artigo é aqui</h2>
            <p>Publicado em <time datetime="2015-03-09T13:00:24+01:00">09 de Março de 2015</time> por <a href="#">Author</a> - <a href="#comments">30 comentários</a></p>
        </header>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </article>

    <article>
        <header>
            <h2>O título do artigo é aqui</h2>
            <p>Publicado em <time datetime="2015-03-09T13:00:24+01:00">09 de Março de 2015</time> por <a href="#">Author</a> - <a href="#comments">15 comentários</a></p>
        </header>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </article>
</section>

<aside>
    <h2>Entre em contato</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</aside>

<footer>
    <p>Copyright 2015 Código Fonte©</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Me brother, ficou simplesmente perfeito. Muito Obrigado. Que fórum dá hora. Gostei demais.

Comment: Valeu! Saiba como agradecer no [tour]. Abs!

Answer (score -1):

na tag onde está inserido o input vc pode inserir flex-nowrap que o problema é solucionado. Atente tbm para o tamanho das colunas e até margem que pode ser grande demais para o necessário para comportar o input. Teste colocando o 'ml' quando a tela estiver em 'md'. Que é o tamanho para telas médias e grandes 'lg' (para celulares com display HD).

Answer (score -3):

Verifique se no seu site existe a tag abaixo:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Tem sim.  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
 <title>Marcos Briseno - Livros</title>